# Is this ok, if computers form domain B cannot access (trusted) domain controller A?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a situation where we have (simplifying a bit) domain controllers for domain A on one subnet and domain controllers for domain B on another subnet. Most of the VMs joined to domain B is also on the subnet where domain controllers for domain B are.

Most users accounts that need access the VMs in either domain are in the domain A.

Domain B is configured with one way trust relationship to Domain A.

Now, we have implemented firewall changes which prevent most of the VMs on the subnet of domain B to access subnet of domain A. The domain controllers still can talk to each other.

This leaded to the situation, that when I want to add a user in domain A to a local group on a VM in subnet B, I no longer can do it - because this VM cannot reach the domain controller in A.

The standard practice though, is to never add users to local group directly like that. Instead, I can create a group "Access to VM1" in Domain A, and add the user there. The I can created "Access to VM1" in Domain B and add "Access to VM1" from Domain A there. Finally, I can Add "Access to VM1" group in Domain B to the local group on VM1. And this works.

Is this a reasonable model? In particular, is it reasonable to limit access of VMs in Domain B to the domain controllers of Domain A? Are there any other problems down the road that it may cause?